# Titled panel (Rectangular named area control) for JavaFX?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

i want to know if there is an implementation of a rectangular named area control in JavaFX like this one "Conditions" :

[image]

Comment: AFAIK no, you need to customize and build yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across with a JavaFX theme named [AeroFX](http://www.guigarage.com/javafx-themes/aerofx/). You can directly use it, or it has a [custom skin](https://github.com/s1gpwr/aerofx/blob/master/aerofx/src/main/java/org/aerofx/controls/skin/AeroGroupBoxSkin.java) for `TitledPane` to look like a panel with title text, you may take that part only obeying on license rights.

Screenshot from its demo:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/ . They have "Borders" which can be used for what you want to achieve.